# Select group by total of 2 tables based on another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 mysql tables as like this: http://pastebin.com/1eH6R3f9

I tryed this query but it myltiplies the amout more than one time. someone please help!

```
SELECT
 m.merchantID,m.merchantName,SUM(pr.dr_amount) 'Total Due', SUM(me.paidAmount) 'Total Paid' 

FROM merchant m 

INNER JOIN product_report pr, merchant_payment me 

WHERE m.merchantID = pr.merchantID AND m.merchantID = me.merchantID 

GROUP BY m.merchantID
```

Comment: Please edit the question and make it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to aggregate the data along each dimension *before* doing the join.  Otherwise, you will get a cartesian product:

```
SELECT m.merchantID, m.merchantName, pr.TotalDue, me.TotalPaid
FROM merchant m LEFT JOIN
     (select pr.merchantId, sum(pr.dr_amount) as TotalDue
      from product_report pr
      group by pr.merchantId
     ) pr
     ON m.merchantId = pr.merchantId LEFT JOIN
     (select me.merchantId, sum(me.paidAmount) as TotalPaid
      from merchant_payment me 
      group by me.merchantId
     ) me
     ON m.merchantId = me.merchantId;
```

In addition:

- Do not mix implicit and explicit joins.  A simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.
- Use single quotes only for string and date constants.  MySQL uses the backtick to escape names when necessary.  Better, however, to use names that do not require escaping.